# How to redirect within the Module and restrict access without exit() in ZF3?

Tags: routes, redirect, exit, zend-framework3

My Zend Framework 3 application manages orders:

- Every user can make an order.
- Every user can see any order.
- Every user can edit his order, if he is the creator of this order. Otherwise he'll get the status code `403` and be redirected to the according page.

Implemented in the `MyModule\Module#onRoute(...)` as follows:

```
public function onRoute(EventInterface $event)
{
    if ($event->getRequest() instanceof HttpRequest) {
        ...
        if (! $acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)) {
            /** @var Response $response */
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $config = $serviceManager->get('config');
            $redirectRoute = ! empty($config['acl']['redirect_route']) ? $config['acl']['redirect_route'] : null;
            if (! empty($redirectRoute)) {
                $url = $event->getRouter()->assemble($redirectRoute['params'], $redirectRoute['options']);
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
                $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_403);
                $response->sendHeaders();
                exit(); // <-- this makes the code untestable
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    } elseif ($event->getRequest() instanceof ConsoleRequest) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's working.  But now, I'm writing integration tests and this `exit()` call breaks them.

**What is the alternative to the `exit()` at this place and a proper/clean way of redirection within the `Module` class?**

Answer (score 0):

It works with the status code `302` (instead of `403`):

```
$response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_302);
```

Answer (score 0):

the Http Resopnse code "403" is not redirectional code, it is just for client errors.

following codes are there for redirection-

```
// REDIRECTION CODES
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        306 => 'Switch Proxy', // Deprecated
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
```

Now as per point

-Every user can edit his order, if he is the creator of this order. Otherwise he'll get the status code 403 and be redirected to the according page.

You should handle it, just redirect to a 403 "Forbidden" page (the page may have your message)